# C# type conversion Help

Tags: c#, list, linq, enumerable

I have a Struct as follows,

```
struct Location
{
    public int Row;
    public int Column;

    public Location(int row, int column)
    {
        this.Row = row;
        this.Column = column;
    }
}
```

and i have a function as follows,

```
public List<Location> getNeighboringLocations(int row, int column)
{
    int[,] array = new int[rows, columns];
    int refx = row;
    int refy = column;

    //var neighbours = from x in Enumerable.Range(refx - 1, 3)
    //                 from y in Enumerable.Range(refy - 1, 3)
    //                 where x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < array.GetLength(0) && y < array.GetLength(1)
    //                 select new { x, y };
    var neighbours = from x in Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(0)).Where(x => Math.Abs(x - refx) <= 1)
                 from y in Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(1)).Where(y => Math.Abs(y - refy) <= 1)
                 select new { x, y };

    return neighbours.ToList();
}
```

I want the return  type be the List of Locations how do i do it?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should refrain from using List<T> as part of your public interface.  Try IList<T> for the same effect, but better flexibility as the code grows.

Comment: neighbours.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine); just prints the values i need but i need to store then in a Location Struct how?

Comment: @GregC: And even arguably `IEnumerable<T>`.  Can also [`yield return x`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: @Brad Christie: That's what I'd do, but it can change the way it's used by client code.  I did not want to go too far with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...

```
select new Location(x, y);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var neighbours = from x in Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(0)).Where(x => Math.Abs(x - refx) <= 1)
                             from y in Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(1)).Where(y => Math.Abs(y - refy) <= 1)
                             select new Location( x, y );

return neighbours.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `select new { x, y }` which returns an anonymous type you should do `select new Location(x, y)`.